# Can I make color data not render as gradient?

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I would like for the color between my vertices to not be rendered as a gradient, but as a hard break. Is there any way to accomplish this in OpenGL/GLSL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try doing this with `flat` attribute qualifier in shaders, like so:

```
flat vec3 surfColor;
```

It tells GLSL to pass values from vertex to fragment without interpolation.

From [GLSL Interpolation qualifiers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers):

> Interpolation qualifiers control how interpolation of values happens
>   across a triangle or other primitive. There are three basic
>   interpolation qualifiers.
>
> **flat**​ The value will not be interpolated. The value given to the
>   fragment shader is the value from the [Provoking Vertex](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive#Provoking_vertex) for that
>   primitive.
>   ...

Additional read on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581271/flat-qualifier-in-glsl

Answer (score 1):

These are two options I know:

1. **Define each triangle seperate with the color you want in each vertex**. Usually vertices are shared between neighboring triangles. If you make each triangle unique you can set the color of each vertex to the color you want the triangle to be. It increases the number of vertices, but unless you have a huge number of objects this is likely not a issue.
2. **Texture it**: make the texturemap of solid colors line up with the vertices and edges. Adds the benefit that you can recolor the model simply by changing the texture.

Both are often used in the 'flatshaded' look.

Comment: I have a huge number of objects (trying to create a large procedurally generated map). Creating textures seems like a pain. Especially if I want to experiment with the color scheme. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=4884 "Single-pass wireframe rendering" describes a technique for rendering models in wireframe using barycentric coordinates.

http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/ gives related code for the technique.

Barycentric coordinates are giving you the distance to each vertex, which could in turn be used to choose the color belonging to the vertex with the closest distance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_(mathematics) describes how to compute the barycentric coordinates.

Once we have the barycentric coordinates of the point on the triangle, we compare the dimensions of the point and determine which one is the smallest. We use this information to index a uniform which holds the vertex colors.

Comment: Please include a summary of the technique in your answer, so that it doesn't lose its value if either of the links above were to become unavailable. Also note that to perform the last step you describe, fragment shader would also need access to [the colour value of] each of the vertices being interpolated for the current primitive. Can you describe how we would access this information?